# PHP class works with Chrome but not with Firefox

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox

I am dealing with a problem where a class works with Chrome but not with Firefox.

```
public function getInstance() {
    if (self::$instance === null) {
        self::$instance = new CartProc();
        self::$instance->init();
    }

    return self::$instance;
}

public function init() { //print_r("tesssssssssssst");exit;
...
```

Here the function `init()` is completely ignored by Firefox. Any experienced programmer out there who knows a generic solution for this? It can be a hook, workaround, whatever.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PHP works on server side, not on client. Your code is not affected by any browser at all.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is executed server side so regardless of what browser you are using as long as your webserver is configured correctly the php code will be executed.

You may want to look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language so any difference between browser should originate in the html/text/javascript produced by the php function. So your functions are not affected by the browser.

So maybe the result of the php function is differently interpreted by the browsers. But then you'll have to show more of the init() function.

What is going wrong? You say the init() function is completely ignored? How do you notice? Why are you printing something in a function and not returning it?